# btrfs: subvolume/snapshot tree

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

How do I list all subvolumes / snapshots on a btrfs filesystem in parent / child hierarchy?

I want something like the `tree` command for directories/files, but for parent/child subvolumes with subvolume ID and the location of the snapshot on disk.

Comment: [This mostly unrelated question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212018/display-btrfs-subvolume-tree) is about listing subvolumes based on filesystem location, rather than parent/child relationship.

Comment: I don't know that there is a provided command for it but a combination of list/show should let you achieve that.